# Javascript: check if the url is changed or not?

Tags: javascript

My url format is like :

```
http://domain.in/home
http://domain.in/books/notes
http://domain.in/books/notes/copy
```

I've called a javascript function on window.load to check if the url has changed or not.

If the url has been changed then code is executed else it will return and checks again after 5 sec.

My code is :

```
window.onload = function(){
   setInterval(function(){
       page_open();
   }, 5000);
};

function page_open(){
    var pages=unescape(location.href);
    pages=pages.substr( pages.lastIndexOf("studysquare.in/") + 15 ); 

    // gives book if url is http://studysquare.in/book
    //alert("pages"+pages+"\n\n  recent"+recent);

    if (pages==recent) {    return;     }
    recent=pages;

    alert("Reached down now the code will execute.");
}
```

The problem now is : when the url is like :

```
http://domain.in/book
```

Single level deep, then everything works fine. But when the url is like

```
http://domain.in/book/copy    or    http://domain.in/book/copy/notes
```

Then nothing works.....
Any help to check 3 level deep url  change in javascript every 5 sec ? :)

Hi sorry I forgot to tell that... I've .htaccess file which doesnt allow to navigate the page when any length url after the `domain.in/` is written.... that means only single page remains open and not affected by the url change...

Comment: You realise that your code's context will be destroyed and a new context created the instant a new page loads? Your code will never detect a change because the current instance of it stops executing when you navigate.

Comment: Hi sorry I forgot to tell that... I've .htaccess file which doesnt allow to navigate the page when any length url after the domain.in/ is written.... that means only single page remains open and not affected by the url change...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by checking if the url has changed?

Comment: just try to open the relative page on the main stable page....

Comment: .htaccess doesn't change the way the browser works. If they change the URL, the browser will still destroy your page's current context and create a new one for it's next request, regardless of .htaccess (which only your server sees, not the browser)

Comment: Can I suggest that you use hashes in the url. For example `http://domain.in/#books/notes/copy`. It doesn't reload the page and works well with javascript.

Comment: Hi Todd.... The .htaccess sends requests to the server like : if the url is http://domain.in/book/notes then it will send the request like http://domain.in/#book/notes so the main page will remain same, the hash changes when the url changes...

Comment: Hi grc... To remove Hashes only i'm trying to do this such extra thing...

Comment: It doesn't matter what the server sends back, the page has already been unloaded in the browser at that point and your code has stopped running.

Answer (score 1):

When the user changes the URL, the browser unloads the entire page they're currently on (including your javascript, hence it stops running) and then loads the next page. No javascript is able to run across page changes. You can't monitor a change in the URL like you're doing if they're navigating to another page.

The best way to catch a change in the URL is to add an `onUnload` event to the body object to fire your javascript when the browser unloads the page just before starting to load the new page the user has requested -- but I'm not sure that's going to help achieve your goal of tracking their recent page views (if that's what you're looking to do).

Comment: Hi I know this... Please tell why its not working with 2 or 3 level deep urls because the url change doesnt change my page... Thanks for the reply

Comment: It won't change because it's NEVER called. The context is destroyed and your "old URL" doesn't exist by the time your code is called on the next page. Think of it like a running process. When you go to a different page, it kills the process and starts a new instance of it. No variables or data is kept, it's all destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a history plugin such as [jQuery address](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/) would help you a lot.

It lets you handle the event when the URL is changed, so you can load in new content as required.